# Apart from JS, do other languages execute code in order of loading?

Tags: javascript, oop

A lot of people (like me) are used to JavaScript in the respect that code is executed in the order of loading, i.e. from top to bottom, so if an element hasn't yet loaded it is impossible to manipulate it, or if a function has not yet been defined it is impossible to call it. Since JS (and VBscript, but that's not too popular) is the only internet client-side programming (scripting, if you wish) language, and therefore the only language to come across the problem of having to be loaded from a different location, I assume that no other language does that, i.e. one can call a function/method in the language, while having defined it later on in the document. Is this assumption correct, or are there other languages that do that too?

EDIT: for those who don't understand what I mean, here's an example in Java:

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeClass SomeObject = new SomeClass;
        SomeObject.changeSomeVariable("someValue");
    }
}
class SomeClass {
    String someVariable;
    void changeSomeVariable(newValue){
        someVariable = newValue;
    }
}
```

Note how the class defining the object goes *after* the line where the object is created. Will the above work (I might have gotten the syntax a bit wrong)?

Comment: Many languages let you call a not defined function. For example in C# or VB.NET. In C/C++ you have to declare the function before you use it but you can define its body later. This is a design choice for the language itself and (I guess) comes from compiler/interpreter design (speed and simplicity) more than because of its use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ (compiled language), for example, you can use a class or a function while you know only its definition, not implementation.

```
int some_function(int i); 
// we know the name of the function, the types of its parameters and
// its return value. We don't know, however, what does this function 
// exactly do.

int main() {
  int x = some_function(42);
}
```

Of course, implementation of the function must be placed somewhere, otherwise linking will fail.

But if we don't know the name or the signature of a function or a class, we can't use it. In opposite to compiled languages, in scripting languages (such as Python, PHP, JavaScript etc) you can do it:

```
function f() {
  return some_function(42);
}
```

This JavaScript function can be created without error even if no `some_function` is defined. But it must have been defined when `f()` is called.

We can talk and talk about these facts relative to some languages. But there are a lot of languages, and they all are different. If you're curious about this question, I can advise you to learn several other languages a bit (at least one compiled and one functional).

Comment: Python isn't scripting... is it?

Comment: Anyway, what I mean is, in JS if a script manipulating an element comes before the element itself (and both are in the body), then it won't work; however, in stuff like Java, if I make an object `SomeClass someObject = new SomeClass`, and then try to do something to it - `someObject.someVariable = "somevalue"`, then if I put that code *before* the code defining the object, will it work?

Comment: @Bluefire "stuff like Java" LOL :) yes, it'll work. It depends on the compiler/interpreter. Image to write an interpreter: what it may do when it parses an unknown identifier? It has to parse everything else to find it or to pre-parse everything before starting execution. This is the most obvious reason to do not do it (and it's specially true for interpreters).

Comment: Another example: PHP is scripting language, but in PHP you can use a function defined below in the file. It's unusual for scripting languages. But it's implemented in the interpreter, so it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Many scripting languages such as PHP and Ruby execute in order.

That is a tenant of scripting languages.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't let a comment. Actually the question is pretty vague but the answer doesn't shed light. Every language executes code somehow in order so his point may be about function declaration and entry points.